# Zooming with "Tiled:True" in WMS layer?

Tags: openlayers-2, tiles

I activate the TILED parameter to True in a WMS Layer and I get the following strange behavior as shown in the images:[image]

[image]

This happens only for a couple zoom levels. If I zoom out/in more the features are rendered in the correct position (as in the first image).

Any idea why is this happening?

Here is my code for the layers:

```
        // layer komvoi
        wms_layer_komvoi = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Όλοι Κόμβοι","http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", 
            {layers: 'rural:komvoi_real',
            transparent: true,
            TILED: true
            },
            {
            format: "image/png",
            visibility: false,
            displayOutsideMaxExtent: false,
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")});
        // layer network    
        wms_layer_network = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Ολόκληρο Δίκτυο", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", 
            {layers: 'rural:foc_network',
            transparent: true,
            TILED: true
            },
            {
            format: "image/png",
            visibility: false,
            displayOutsideMaxExtent: false,
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")},
            {
            }); 

        // add layers
        map.addLayers([wms_layer_komvoi,wms_layer_network,wms]); // first you put the layer with the points
        map.zoomToExtent( new OpenLayers.Bounds(36.190737, 35.353912,35.150577, 50.274810));
        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(22.228697,37.650344), 8);
```

Comment: doesn't your geoserver deliver the WMS-tiles as 256x256px tiles by default?

Comment: WMS aren't tile servers, so they have no default tile sizes configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to set the tilesorigin and tilesize

--> tileOrigin  {OpenLayers.LonLat}

x and y are the coordinates of the lower left corner (the “origin”) of the tile grid system

```
    new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
    "xxxxxx","url",
    {layers: 'xx:xxx', format: 'image/png' },
    { tileOrigin: new OpenLayers.LonLat(-180, -90),
tileSize: new OpenLayers.Size(256,256)});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/6g3q8hcv/

see http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html section "tiled"